# jQuery Checkboxes in Safari

Tags: jquery, checkbox, blur

I am trying to add a class when a checkbox is "checked" in Safari and remove it when it is unchecked [in other browsers I am using.bind("focus", function() { but in Safari it doesnt work?]

I am currently using

```
jQuery('.top_class input').bind("focus", function(){
jQuery(this).parents('.row').addClass("add_over"); 
            })
            .bind("blur", function() { 
jQuery(this).parents('.row').removeClass("add_over"); 
            });
```

This doesnt work in Safari - how to get the code to work in safari ?

Comment: @Thomas, if your latest edit is accurate, you are adding the class in both situations. You need `removeClass` in the `blur` function.

Comment: oh yeah sorry :) i fixed that but in Safari it doesnt work ?

Comment: I figured it out. Safari only allows `focus` and `blur` on checkboxes depending on User Accessibility settings. I added an update with code I tested in Safari. If it works, be sure to mark it as "accepted" so we both get rep and future searchers know what solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with a traditional `input[type=checkbox]` then I think you are looking for the click event, something like this:

```
jQuery('.top_class').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.row').toggleClass("add_over", jQuery(this).is(':checked') );
});
```

To be clear, this will work if this is your checkbox HTML (more or less):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="top_class" name="whatever" />
```

**UPDATE**: Safari may or may not accept `focus` on a checkbox depending on settings. Since there is no way to test this, I would handle it this way:

```
var $rows = jQuery('.row'); // Cache all rows
jQuery('.top_class').click(function(){
    var $row = jQuery(this).closest('.row');
    $rows.filter(".add_over").not($row).removeClass("add_over"); // Remove class from other rows
    $row.addClass('add_over');
});
```

That should do what you want. You can see a DEMO of it working in Safari here: http://jsbin.com/ohuxe/

Comment: This should do both if you are using a normal `input` checkbox. Every-time the element is clicked it checks and unchecks. This turns the parent elements class on or off based on checked status.

Comment: yeah thanks :) is it possible to use something similar - when a user checks the box, then "add over" remains on while it is focused on ".top_class" - if user moves onto another element it removes ? [checkbox is within top_class]

Comment: Hey, I have an idea, edit your original question and include the HTML from `.top_class` down to the actual `input[checked]` element. I probably can give better advice then.

Comment: hey updated the code I am using in other browsers - this doesnt work in safari ?

Comment: yeah thanks but I think there is some problem with .focus() in safari - something about needing to use .change() ?

Comment: Haha, glad to help. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .bind("click") and checking the checked attribute?

```
jQuery("input.top_class").bind(
     "click", 
      function() { alert(jQuery(this).attr("checked")) }
     )
```

Comment: @Levi, anything indented one tab or four spaces will be considered a `pre` + `code` block and will retain formatting and indentation.